# Remove 7th to 14th character in string on every row from row 26 Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a simple solution to delete the 7th to 14th character (8 in total) from every string in every row from row 26 in Google sheets via a script?

I have played around with some formulas but had no luck and wonder if a script would be a better solution?

Any tips or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tend to use Replace:

```
=ArrayFormula(replace(A26:A,7,8,""))
```

If the string is between 7 and 14 characters in length, this will just return the first 6 characters. If it's less than 7, it will return the whole string.

---

If you did want to use a script, it would look something like this:

```
function myReplace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  r1=sheet.getRange("A26:A")
  r2=sheet.getRange("B26:B")

  data=r1.getValues();

  for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
    data[i][0] = data[i][0].toString().substring(0,6) + data[i][0].toString().substring(14);
  }
  r2.setValues(data);
}
```

If you really wanted to overwrite the original data, you could change  the last line to

```
r1.setValues(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
=arrayformula(if(len(A26:A), substitute(A26:A, mid(A26:A, 7, 8),),))
```

Change range to suit and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I went with Tom Sharpes script solution in the end :)